# Native app crash - getting memory address issue - com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so & #00 0x00000000afef03c4 <unknown>

Tags: android, android-ndk, 32bit-64bit, ndk-build

I am working on the migration of the 32bit NDK project to 64bit.
We are calling so many libs in projects:
like - libssl.so, libcrypto.so, libc.so, liblog.so, libcrashlytics.so

In project going to read kernel process by fopen but somehow, I am getting FATAL signal error and Android logcat showing as below

> A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr
> 0xafef03c4 in tid 12462 (eradocs.android), pid 12462 (eradocs.android)

========================
Below Crash dump found on stack-trace

> #00 0x00000000afef03c4   - This memory address is matching with above fatal signal error.
>
> #06 0x000000000013f350 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+144) (BuildId:
> d700c52998d7d76cb39e2001d670e654)
>
> #07 0x00000000001365b8 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId:
> d700c52998d7d76cb39e2001d670e654)
>
> #08 0x000000000014500c /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int,
> art::JValue*, char const*)+276) (BuildId:
> d700c52998d7d76cb39e2001d670e654)
>
> #09 0x00000000002e2928 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*,
> art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+384)
> (BuildId: d700c52998d7d76cb39e2001d670e654)
>
> #10 0x00000000002ddb88 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*,
> art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short,
> art::JValue*)+892) (BuildId: d700c52998d7d76cb39e2001d670e654)
>
> #11 0x00000000005a28ac /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+372) (BuildId: d700c52998d7d76cb39e2001d670e654)
>
> #12 0x0000000000130994 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20) (BuildId:
> d700c52998d7d76cb39e2001d670e654)
>
> #14 0x00000000002b3c3c /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so

Can anyone help me with this stacktrace? Is there a way to find the root cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

I bet one of your libraries makes use of the `funopen` trick to be able to read assets from native code. That trick used to work, but as both Android and the NDK evolved, the hack soon became more or less obsolete. I used it until I upgraded the NDK and got a similar crash.

See NDK issue [#562](https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/562) and this old [blog post](http://www.50ply.com/blog/2013/01/19/loading-compressed-android-assets-with-file-pointer/). Both mention this `SIGSEGV` error.

Some quick pointers include:

- Check if `_BSD_SOURCE` is defined.
- Did you upgrade the NDK?
- Did you change `minSdkVersion`?
- Did you change from `gcc` to `Clang`?

My solution to this crash was to avoid `funopen` entirely.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I go through link but in my project fopen function is of stdio.h. minsdkversion is 24

Comment: One of your libraries might be using `funopen` to **re-map** `fopen`. You have to check with the authors of each one of the libraries.

Comment: is there any other way to check that which lib is using funopen? Is this link helpful to check - https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-debugger?